# no permissionas for setting Authorized JavaScript origins in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker, developer-console

i want to set my uri inside Authorized JavaScript origins

but it gaves me

> You do not have permission to perform this action.
>
> Tracking Number: c527557048

the steps of the block of Enable APIs and credentials.

1. Access the automatically created apps script Developer Console Project by go to your new project project Resources > Developers Console Project.
2. Click on the blue link at the top (####### - project-id-##########) to access the correct Developer Console Project.
3. On Dashboard click Enable API and search for Google Picker API and enable it.
4. In Credentials section click on Create Credentials and select API keys to create an API key.
5. Click on the API key you just created and put Key restriction to HTTP referrers. Then add *.google.com/* and *.googleusercontent.com/* to your referrers. Save the changes.
6. Click on the Client ID on the same Credentials section, add the origin URI of the client application to Authorized JavaScript origin. Save the changes.

[image]

Comment: What means "Tracking Number"? What did yo do to get that error?

Comment: i am following some steps to install google app script and im stuck in last step in Enable APIs and credentials which  is

 Click on the Client ID on the same Credentials section, add the origin URI of the client application to Authorized JavaScript origin. Save the changes.

Comment: What instructions? What do you mean by "google apps script"? The Google Apps Script Editor is a web application executed on Google's servers, so there isn't anything to install.

Comment: Add the link to the instructions, and the relevant parts to your question.

Comment: @Rubén I am afraid the link is not accessible so i have edited my question please check it

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem; did you ever find a solution?